Getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img' referenced before assignment while applying craft-text-detector to image in python
I'm trying to get image crops using craft-text-detector in python.
Using craft-text-detector==0.4.3 torch==1.11.0 torchvision==0.12.0 numpy==1.23.0
Code:
# import craft functions
from craft_text_detector import (
    Craft,
    read_image,
    load_craftnet_model,
    load_refinenet_model,
    get_prediction,
    export_detected_regions,
    export_extra_results,
    empty_cuda_cache
    )

# set image path and export folder directory
output_dir = '/tmp/advance-outputs/'

# construct full path to the image
image_path = 'sample-images/image.jpg'
         
refine_net = load_refinenet_model(cuda=False)
craft_net = load_craftnet_model(cuda=False)
        
craft = Craft(output_dir=output_dir, crop_type="poly", cuda=False)  # Create the Craft instance here

# apply craft text detection to the current image and export detected regions
prediction_result = craft.detect_text(image_path)

# read image
image = read_image(image_path)

# load models
        
# perform prediction
prediction_result = get_prediction(
 image=image,
 craft_net=craft_net,
 refine_net=refine_net,
 text_threshold=0.7,
 link_threshold=0.4,
 low_text=0.4,
 cuda=False,
 long_size=1280
 )

# export detected text regions
exported_file_paths = export_detected_regions(
image=image,
regions=prediction_result["boxes"],
output_dir=output_dir,
rectify=True
)

# export heatmap, detection points, box visualization
export_extra_results(
 image=image,
 regions=prediction_result["boxes"],
 heatmaps=prediction_result["heatmaps"],
 output_dir=output_dir
)

# unload models from gpu
empty_cuda_cache()


Above code is working fine and saving image-crops in /tmp/advance-outputs.
But above code is taking image_path, I want to give it PIL Image. For this I have change image_path into PIL Image:
from PIL import Image
from craft_text_detector import (
    Craft,
    read_image,
    load_craftnet_model,
    load_refinenet_model,
    get_prediction,
    export_detected_regions,
    export_extra_results,
    empty_cuda_cache
    )


output_dir = '/tmp/advance-outputs/'

image_path = 'sample-images/image.jpg'

pil_image = Image.open(image_path)
         
refine_net = load_refinenet_model(cuda=False)
craft_net = load_craftnet_model(cuda=False)
        
craft = Craft(output_dir=output_dir, crop_type="poly", cuda=False)  

        
prediction_result = get_prediction(
 image=pil_image,
 craft_net=craft_net,
 refine_net=refine_net,
 text_threshold=0.7,
 link_threshold=0.4,
 low_text=0.4,
 cuda=False,
 long_size=1280
 )

exported_file_paths = export_detected_regions(
image=pil_image,
regions=prediction_result["boxes"],
output_dir=output_dir,
rectify=True
)

export_extra_results(
 image=pil_image,
 regions=prediction_result["boxes"],
 heatmaps=prediction_result["heatmaps"],
 output_dir=output_dir
)

empty_cuda_cache()
`

But this code is giving me error:
$ python3 text_detection_advanced.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../pythoncode/text_detection_advanced.py", line 339, in <module>
    prediction_result = get_prediction(
  File "../site-packages/craft_text_detector/predict.py", line 47, in get_prediction
    image = image_utils.read_image(image)
  File "../site-packages/craft_text_detector/image_utils.py", line 28, in read_image
    return img
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img' referenced before assignment

Guide me where I'm doing wrong, and how can I surpass this error.

The module simply does not support PIL images; the allowed types for the image parameter are strings (interpreted as a filename), bytes (interpreted as encoded image data), or a Numpy array.  Try passing the filename, rather than trying to read the image yourself.

Are you sure the image paths exist?

As this image load function is a library import function, most likely your path is invalid.

That being said..
From looking at your traceback:

First, You need to create the variable 'img' before it is returned, regardless of the rest of the code, this is good practice and prevents exception

Second, the Traceback you have provided states you are assigning to 'image' not 'img', so 'img' is never set:
image = image_utils.read_image(...)
#should be:
img = image_utils.read_image(...)

Third, it is good practice to check the file exists before accessing either way.
So I suggest:
imgPath = "<Your path>"
img = 0
if os.path.exists(ImgPath):
    img =  image_utils.read_image(ImgPath)
return img
    ...
if img not 0:
   <Rest of your code>

Good luck!

Take a closer look at the traceback; the problem is occurring inside the module, rather than in the user's own code.

As I mentioned in the answer, if the problem is inside a module, the problem is most likely bad path, this is the first part of my response.
